# I am stuck with how to get last month data from one year using for loop and function

Tags: pandas, for-loop, pandas-groupby

[This is the dataframe. My output should contain last month sales quantity and return quantity as column.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1esr.png)

I wrote this code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfI0B.png) and I don't know what should be in groupby.

My output should have ALL the columns and sales quantity should be last month sales quantity and return quantity should last month return quantity.

Comment: Please read the guidelines, do not post images of data/code. Update your question to replace them with text, that can be easily copy pasted.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How to post a DF as a text?